# UML Plugin for Netbeans 7.0?

Tags: plugins, uml, netbeans-plugins, netbeans7.0

how can i install/add UML plugin to Netbeans 7.0, i can find several ways to install plugin but only for the earlier versions from 6.9

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic28035.html its not working for me.

Comment: NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201112080600) does not work anything from old version. You should have two version, one is oldest which have and works. And if you are happy with 7.0 use it seperate. On the other hand use JBuilder for free

Comment: This might help you http://www.visual-paradigm.com/resource/netbeans-plugin.jsp

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is how to install on 7.1 (should also work for 7.0)

Add a new configuration to update centers:
`Tools -> Plugins -> Settings -> Add`

As the URL copy the following into the textbox: `http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/catalog.xml`

Now on the tab `Available Plugins` there should be `UML` in category `UML`

Comment: I've installed it but I have no idea how to use it - there is no new entry in any menu!

Comment: Have you looked at adding a project? I think the option for UML charts is a project type or something to that effect.

Sucks Netbeans 7.3 doesn't include that functionality as a core plugin though :(

Comment: Has been reported to work on the daily builds for 7.4 as well. Just be aware of some major bugs still present.

Comment: In 7.3, I added the update center as specified, but plugin does not appear in Available Plugins list. Same thing happened when I tried [this URL](http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/uml/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml) Any suggestions?
Maybe, it would be cool to have an option to download the plugin file separately, and install it then.

Comment: this is still working in Netbeans7.3, but you need to change `dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net` to `dlc.sun.com`.

Answer (score 1):

previous don't work, use this link [netbeans 6.7.1 plugin container](http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.7.1/uc/final/beta/catalog.xml.gz)

Answer (score 1):

For new versions of Netbeans you can use this [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49069/plantuml#v2590), It's updated for 7.x..