# Creating UML Class Diagrams in NetBeans 7.1.1

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, netbeans-7.1

I want to install/enable the NetBeans plugin for creating and viewing UML diagrams, as seen [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/b/b8/Vista_Nimbus_Uml_Screenshot_NBLookAndFeels.JPG). However, fairly extensive searching has turned up results for NetBeans 6.5 and lower, whereas I am using NetBeans 7.1.1. (I've tried those solutions, though, but to no avail; what they said should be in the IDE was not, such as the Update Manager) **Does anyone know how to get NetBeans 7.1.1 to show UML diagrams of Java projects?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Netbeans 6.7 was the last version to support UML. For 7.1, there's (1) a semi-broken workaround and (2) [yWorks UML Doclet](http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html#yDoc), which will let you generate diagrams. See [this](http://michelelepri.blogspot.com/2012/03/netbeans-70-and-71-uml-plugin.html) for more details.

**Edit**: You can [install the UML plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944002/uml-plugin-for-netbeans-7-0/8987726#8987726) manually on 7.1.

Comment: I followed the instructions therein to a T, but when building the Javadoc, I consistently get "`javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class ydoc.doclets.YStandard`". I confirmed that I'm giving it the correct classpath and that the JAR is not corrupted

Comment: BIG thanks @blackcompe I spend my days looking for yWorks, now I found it.

Answer (score 24):

Here is how to install on 7.1

Add a new configuration to update centers: Tools -> Plugins -> Settings -> Add

As the URL copy the following into the textbox: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/catalog.xml

Now on the tab Available Plugins there should be UML in category UML.
Install the plugin, and its done..!!

Comment: At least you should have mentioned that you copied DKSan's answer from here, so credit goes for him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944002/uml-plugin-for-netbeans-7-0/8987726#8987726.

Comment: Well, the package installed correctly in NetBeans 7.4, but when I make a reverse engineer project from a Java project, the models are simply not imported. Seems like some error with generics: ".java(line=88, col=96) : unexpected token: >"

Answer (score 0):

How use Visual Paradigm Integrated with Net Beans

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/modelinginnetbeans.jsp