# Netbeans changed after UML installed

Tags: uml, netbeans

I installed and used a UML plugin found here: [UML Plugin for Netbeans 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944002/uml-plugin-for-netbeans-7-0/8987726#8987726)

Afterword, all of my .java code associated with the UML became black and white and un-editable. Although, I can write extra text it cannot be deleted. Running my project results in "Cannot execute - java executable not found".

I deleted the UML files associated with my projects and the code hasn't returned to normal.
Thanks.

Here is a picture:
[image]

This actually occurred to all java files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Eclipse, different versions of NetBeans are so different that plugins made for younger versions (6) DO NOT work on later versions (8) by default. You can upgrade only subversions steps (digits after dot) without changing plugins. So you have used two pieces of SW that need not be compatible at all. You used a workaround to make to work the installation. And you can get absolutely any consequences, don't be surprised.

The history of the problem: there is no free UML plugin supporting NetBeans NOW. There was one, of Visual Paradigm, for versions to 6. But it's later variants are not free anymore and they are differently organized. If you want to use the modern version of the plugin, prepare to pay. It is very probable, that the free plugin doesn't work on NetBeans 8 by purpose.

You can try a new different plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49069/plantuml#v2590 of another author. It seems more simple, but at least it won't destroy your IDE. And now you have to save the project, reinstall NetBEans and import the project again.

Comment: Thanks Gangnus. The UML support isn't that important to me. I'll reinstall NetBeans.